# Python Dictonary or List with String|Int data structure with sorting

Tags: python, python-2.7

I need some sort of way to be able to append keys & data to a list to then manipulate that data. I then need to sort the list descending and be able to print off both the key and the value.

```
list = []
goal scored by team:
 (check key England isn't in list)
  list.append("England", 0)
 else
  list["England"] = list["England"] + 1

 (check key England isn't in list)
  list.append("Scotland", 0)
 else
  list["Scotland"] = list["Scotland"] + 1

sortdescend(list)

print(list[0])
> "Germany", 25
print(list[1])
> "England", 10
print(list[2])
> "France", 8
```

Comment: You can use an ordered dict. `collections.OrderedDict`.

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/howto/sorting.html

Comment: You seem to be confusing the Python list with the dictionary. Read up on both of them in a tutorial and see if that helps.